# NextCloud Desktop Client users migration to a new server

Tags: powershell, client, desktop, nextcloud

I was asked to write a PowerShell script which is able to read the NextCloud username (I take it from the client files in appdata\roaming), recover the new username and password from a csv and then I have to use these information to login the user so it will unblock the client. I am able to login the client with the new user but it is waiting for the "app password" (I'm not sure about that).

I found this function by Saggiehaim

```
function Connect-NextcloudServer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [PSCredential]$Credential,
        [string]$Server,
        [switch]$NoSSL
    )

    $creds = "{0}:{1}" -f $Credential.UserName, $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($creds))
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
    $Headers = @{
        Authorization    = $basicAuthValue
        'OCS-APIRequest' = 'true'
    }

    if ($NoSSL) {
        $UrlPrefix = 'http://'
    }
    else {
        $UrlPrefix = 'https://'
    }

    $NextcloudBaseURL = $UrlPrefix + $Server
    Write-Verbose "NextcloudBaseURL: $NextcloudBaseURL"


    try {
        $r = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $Headers -Uri "$NextcloudBaseURL/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users?search=&format=json&limit=1" -ErrorVariable:fail
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Nextcloud Server could not be contacted please check the server URL: $NextcloudBaseURL"
    }


    if ($r.ocs.meta.status -eq 'ok') {
        Write-Verbose "Connected to Nextcloud Server: $Server"
        $Script:NextcloudAuthHeaders = $Headers
        $Script:NextcloudBaseURL = $NextcloudBaseURL
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "Failed to Authenticate to Nextcloud Server: $Server. Server returned: $($fail.message.split(',') | select-string statuscode) "
    }
}
```

It looks like it's working (I log in) but the output doesn't contain the app password.
I don't know nothing about NextCloud, it has been deployed by a colleague of mine. I suppose it is a matter of URL where I send the request. By the way I'd like to learn how to simply insert automatically username and password in the login page in the browser.
Can you help me?

Comment: Why on earths does a csv list with users and passwords exist? Where does _that_ come from?

Comment: The target is to automate transition from old Nextcloud server to the new one where passwords will be renewed. The most of our shopkeepers are not able to do this on their own, and I can't spend too much time doing the migration for everyone by phone or remote desktopp applications.

Comment: The CSV file is the one used to create many users in one time.

Comment: So it is not the actual passwords, but just a hash, right? Not sure what kind of user backend you are using. But certainly one _never_ stores passwords in a database! NEVER!